# Unable to send Array of Dictionary in Alamofire multiform data Request

Tags: ios, swift, networking, alamofire

I'm trying to send array of dictionary with images in alamofile Multiform data.But it returns error **Expected a dictionary, but got str** **for product_review_skin_concerns**

Here's the code:

```
    func uploadReviewFiles(method:HTTPMethod,imagesData:[Data],imageKey:String,parm:Parameters,header:HTTPHeaders,url:String,comp:@escaping(Result<Data,AFError>)->Void){
    AF.upload(multipartFormData: { (multipartFormData) in
        for data in imagesData{
            multipartFormData.append(data, withName: imageKey, fileName: "\(Date().timeIntervalSince1970).png", mimeType: "image/png")
        }
        
        
        for (key, value) in parm {
            if  key == "product_review_skin_concerns"{
                guard let arr = value as? [[String:Any]] else{return}
                for val in arr{
                   
                    multipartFormData.append("\(val)".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, withName: key)
                }
                
            }else{
                multipartFormData.append("\(value)".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, withName: key)
            }
            
            
           
            
        }
        
    }, to: url,method: method,headers: header).validate(statusCode: 200..<299).responseData { (data) in
        switch data.result{
        case .success(let recivedData):
            print(NSString(data: recivedData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue) ?? "Unable to pring string value of data")
            comp(.success(recivedData))
            
        case .failure(let error):
            comp(.failure(error))
            print(error)
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            
        }
    }
    
}
```

This the parm parameter I'm posting with image

```
["cons": "Test Review", "product": "9a66dc08-a54f-4af4-928c-14e760af9e8e", "rate": 3, "pros": "Test Review", "product_review_skin_concerns": [["skin_concern": "a2d92030-93f3-4c71-a834-1a6a1b937183", "percent": 0], ["percent": 0, "skin_concern": "8ea0ab47-1c1a-4a78-ae62-91da250a09c9"], ["skin_concern": "717811f1-0a87-4ed0-8561-5c8a10c3968c", "percent": 0]]]
```

Comment: You're only appending an interpolated string description of the dictionary. It likely expects some specific format, so you'll need to figure out what that format is and convert the dictionary value to it during upload.

Comment: @JonShier I'm sending the same parm in postman, somehow it's working with postman.

Comment: It seems likely Postman is encoding the dictionary for you, so you need to figure out what that encoding is and apply it here.

Answer (score 0):

**initialize Variables**

```
var invitationsArray = Array<[String: Any]>()
var invitations = Array<[String: Any]>()
```

**Logic**

```
    invitations = [["friend_id": "\(each.friendId!)", "invited_type": "friend"]]
                    invitationsArray.append(contentsOf: invitations)
```

**Set variables**

```
let params: [String: Any] = [
            "user_id":Global.shared.currentUserLogin.id,
            "ride_name": planARide.name!,
            "ride_description": planARide.description!,
            "ride_type": planARide.rideType!,
            "ride_date_and_time": planARide.rideDate!,
            "ride_city": planARide.city!,
            "ride_meeting_spot": planARide.rideMeetingSpot!,
            "ride_meeting_latitude": planARide.latitude!,
            "ride_meeting_longitude": planARide.longitude!,
            "ride_intensity": planARide.rideIntensity!,
            "time_length_of_ride": planARide.rideTime!,
            "reoccuring_ride": planARide.rideReccurring!,
            "special_instructions": planARide.specialInstruction!,
            "open_ride_to_biking_community": planARide.openRideToBikingCommunity!,
            "invitations": invitationsArray
        ]
```

**AF Request Like this**

```
func requestWithHeaderandBody(vc:UIViewController , url:String , params:[String:Any] , method:HTTPMethod = .post, type:String = "", loading:Bool = true){
        
        let loaderVC : LoaderViewController =  UIStoryboard.controller()
        
        if CheckInternet.Connection(){
            if loading{
                            
                loaderVC.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
                vc.present((loaderVC), animated: false, completion: nil)
            }
            
            AF.request( Apis.baseURL + url , method: method, parameters: params , encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseJSON { (response) in
                
                switch response.result{
                
                case .success(let value):

                    
                    let json = JSON(value)
                    let status = json["status"].stringValue
                    let message = json["message"].stringValue
                    if status == "200"{
                        print("Sucessfully APi Hit")
                        if let del = self.delegate{
                            loaderVC.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
                            del.onSuccess(json: json, val: type)
                        }
                    }else if status == "400"{
                        loaderVC.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)

                        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {

                            vc.showAlertWithOk(withTitle: Alert.String.alert, withMessage: json["message"].stringValue)
                        }
                        
                    }
                    

                
                case .failure(let err):
                    err.localizedDescription
                    loaderVC.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
                    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
                        vc.showAlertWithOk(withTitle: Alert.String.alert, withMessage: "Service Failure \(err.localizedDescription)")
                    }
                    break
                }
            }
        }else{
            print("No internet connection")
        }
    }
```